# Left and right align links in <nav>

Tags: css, html, nav

Is there a prettier and/or better way to align some `a`-elements in a `nav` to the right, while keeping others on the left, than using floats?
`float:right` moves the floated elements to the top of the `nav` instead of keeping them where they used to be, height-wise.
This has to be a common enough problem to have a good solution. `clear:both;`-divs or css to fix the damages aren't really pretty solutions.

This is basically the code I have.

```
<nav>
  <!-- left-aligned -->
    <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.svg" /></a>
    <a href="#">Foo</a>
    <a href="#">Bar</a>
  <!-- right-aligned -->
    <a href="#">Potato</a>
    <a href="#">Tomato</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: did you try adding classes to <a> ? I am not sure that is most elegant way but it will probably work.  Add float: left; and float: right; You may also use 2 <ul> one left one right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add classes to your a's, like shown in html.

html:

```
   <nav>
      <!-- left-aligned -->
        <a class="left" href="#"><img src="img/logo.svg" /></a>
        <a class="left" href="#">Foo</a>
        <a class="left" href="#">Bar</a>
      <!-- right-aligned -->
        <a class="right" href="#">Potato</a>
        <a class="right" href="#">Tomato</a>
    </nav>
```

and css:

```
nav .left {
    float: left;
}

nav .right {
    float: right;
}
```

Also, after you do that, and if doesn't work, you may want to make sure your nav's width is long enough, so they don't all scrunch together. Like `nav { width: 100%; }`

Comment: This does require a float:left as well as the float:right, but maybe it's the best solution.